# Perl Distributed Job Queue

Tags: perl, unix, job-scheduling

I need to setup a job queue where long running job queues are scheduled via a web interface. And are then run on multiple boxes. I also need the ability to remove and reorder jobs in the queue.

Currently all our code is in perl. I was looking in to using something like ApacheMQ, Gearman, Resque, etc...

The question, Would one of the ones mentioned before be better suitable for the job, what about a different software solution? I was originality planning just writing a MySQL/Perl queue, but that's quite difficult. I would prefer something with a decent web interface, and have an interface into Perl. A pure MySQL/Perl would be ideal.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Yes, writing a good one yourself is quite difficult.  Here's what I can tell you from my experience:

TheSchwartz on CPAN is a good reliable job queue that uses mysql as a backing store.

Gearman is an unreliable but low-latency queue, with a different feature set.

Neither of those have a web interface, but they have good command-line interfaces to see what's being worked on and what the state is of the queues.

You can use an MQ message queue as a solution, but those are message-passing queues, not quite the same as job management, and you'll have to handle things like scheduling and retries and failures yourself.

I've seen ActiveMQ accessed through Perl via STOMP tried and fail in two projects now.

RabbitMQ is super-stable (go, Erlang!) and quite effective.

Both of those have nice web interfaces for the message queuing part.

Comment: Thanks. Looking through the CPAN Documentation on TheSchwartz, I couldn't find any way of reordering jobs. Also, It looks like those jobs are being pulled in random order?(each job can take 30 min to run, so users wont be happy with random order). Also, I am not sure if more than one job can run at one time. Also, I need the scorecard system to be DB Based, as Jobs will run on different machines, and I need a status page. 

I can handle the scheduling part of things. What I really need is to have a add_job and get_job method, as well as reorder_jobs, get_status, list_all_jobs methods.